# Retrieve posts of users I dont follow LeftJoin Sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables: Users, Community & Posts.

I want to retrieve posts of users that Joe dont follow `(id_user=1)`

**Users**

```
    id_user  |  name
       1        Joe
       2        Doe
       3        Moe
       4        Roe
       5        Clin
```

**Community**

```
  id_follower | id_followed
       1            3
       1            5
```

**Posts**

```
    id_post   | id_user | post  
      24            4       hi
      25            5       hello
      26            1       how are you
      27            3       come on
      28            4       let go
      29            2       get out
```

What I'm expecting to retrieve is

```
      24            4       hi - by Roe
      28            4       let go  - by Roe
      29            2       get out  - by Doe
```

I tried this but not working

```
SELECT p*
FROM community as c
LEFT JOIN users as u ON u.id_user=c.id_followed
LEFT JOIN posts as p ON p.id_user!=c.id_followed 
WHERE c.id_follower=1 AND u.id_user!=1
```

Comment: If MySQL is like other databases, filtering on a outer joined table in the where clause, `u.id_user` in your case, makes that join an inner join.

Comment: `not exists` should solve your OP

Comment: The order the tables are joined makes a big difference..try starting at posts, not community.

Comment: but I would need to use a subquery then....

Comment: @Twelfth for some reasons it doesnt work starting at posts.

Comment: Starting at community gives you ID 3 and 5, joining to users doesn't add anything, and joining to posts will give you just the posts from user ID 3 and 5...the ones you don't want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
select * from Posts 
where id_user not in
(select id_followed from Community where id_follower = 1)
```

Comment: @joe This is the simpler method of approaching this...left join works and all, but not in works for you here...left join where is null and where not it express the same thing

Answer (score 1):

No point just giving an answer, lets step through the logic.  There are other methods of doing this, but since you asked left join I will do as left join.  Start at posts...

```
from posts p
```

lets then left join to community

```
left join community c on c.id_followed = p.id_user and ID_follower = 1
```

This now gives you a list of all posts along with a community id_followed record...if the record from community is null, then it's from a user joe does not follow.  Since we only want the records joe does not follow

```
where c.id_followed is null
```

We will add a join to users to grab the poster name and put it all together

```
from posts p
left join community c on c.id_followed = p.id_user and ID_follower = 1
left join users u on u.id_user = p.id_user
where c.id_followed is null
```

and finally put together the select line to get the fields you want, using concat to get the post by name format you want

```
select p.id_post, p.id_user,  concat(p.post  , ' by ', u.name)
```

put it together and run!

Comment: ....awesome logic! I dont get why `c.id_followed` should be `null` though

Comment: @joe - in a left join you are preserving all columns in the table on the left (this is why order of tables joined matters, a right join does the same thing except preserves the columns in the table on the right while an inner join drops rows that are not present in the table you inner join to).   So the left join preserves all rows in the posts table, populating c.id_followed when it finds one and leaving it null when it doesn't...since we are only looking for the ones that it doesn't find a c.id_followed for, we then look for c.id_followed to be null.   Hope that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

you  could use a inner join on a not in

```
select p.*
from  Posts p 
inner join (
  select id_user form community 
  where id_user  not in (
   select id_followed
   from community 
   where id_follower =1
  )
) t  on p.id_user = t.id_user and p.id_user <>1
```